# How do I beat the Siren without any magic or items?

Tags: final-fantasy-5

I'm playing Final Fantasy V. Right after the giving my characters jobs, I went to the first village and couldn't really afford any magic - just Poisona for my white mage.

Now I'm in the ship graveyard area, and can't beat the Siren. And, apparently I can't go back to the village to buy any new magic spells.

As far as items go, I have barely anything - no potions, no Phoenix Downs, just a couple of Antidotes.

It seems like at this point my only recourse is to start over, because I can't seem to defeat the Siren. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Siren's HP is 900, so if you think you can do that much damage to her than keep trying. If not then load a save from town.

Comment: I wound up deciding to give this just one more shot (what an awful game design!), and managed to pull it out after walking around a bit to level! Thanks for giving me the confidence. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have bought the fire and cure spells back at the previous town (for WHM and BLM. Fire is a real killer here) but barring that your best bet is to use Monk and the Knight classes to cause damage to her physical form.
She has two modes:

1. Physical attack mode (weakness to mele attacks)
2. Undead mode (magic weakness)